# CGContextFillRect occurred unexpected color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-graphics

When I use `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` and `CGContextFillRect` to fill a rect in a CGBitmapContext, the final color depends on the rect size.

Here is my code.  My problem is that if I change `size_w` to 2 or other size, it will cause unexpected rgba data.

```
int size_w=51;
GLubyte *const data=malloc(size_w*size_w*sizeof(GLubyte)*4);

CGContextRef context= CGBitmapContextCreate(data, size_w, size_w, 8, size_w*4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);

CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor);

CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size_w, size_w));

CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGImageRef cimage= CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
//print the rgba data
struct RGBA* tmp=(struct RGBA*)data;

    for (int i=0; i<size_w*size_w; i++) {

       struct RGBA pixel=tmp[i];
       NSLog(@"r:%i,g:%i,b:%i,a:%i\n",pixel.R,pixel.G,pixel.B,pixel.A);

    }
});
```

Struct `RGBA` is defined as follows:

```
struct RGBA {
    uint8_t R;
    uint8_t G;
    uint8_t B;
    uint8_t A;
};
```

Comment: if the fill color do not contain alpha,the code is not bug.                                 but if use CGContextSetAlpha or the fill color contain alpha value ,like [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5], it will occurred unexpected ruba value.

Comment: i fixed my code with 2 improvement:
1.calloc replace malloc
 or 2.CGContextClearRect before CGContextFillRect.
but why???